# Computing the limit with L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Problem**:
>
> $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{3n^2 - n^2 + n - 1}{1 - n + n^3 - 2n^5}$

**What I tried**

1. $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{4n + 1}{- 1 + 3n^2 - 10n^4}$
2. $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{4}{6n - 40n^3}$

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do after this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Based on your last four questions, I'd bet $100 that you're attending the University of Auckland.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is $0$ because $6n-40n^{3} \to -\infty$. [ $6n-40n^{3}= -n^{3}(40-\frac 6 {n^{2}})$].

Answer (score 0):

Applying L'Hopital's rule twice gives us the expression in the form $-1/\infty \to 0$.

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{\color{red}{n}\to \infty}\dfrac{3n^2-n^2+n-1}{1-n+n^3-2n^5}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{6n-2n+1}{-1+3n^2-10n^4}\\&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{4}{6n-40n^3}\to 0\end{aligned}$$

---

**Aliter**:

Dividing numerator and denominator by the highest power prevailing in the expression is usually another way to find limits of rational expressions especially when the variable tends to $\infty$.

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{\color{red}{n}\to \infty}\dfrac{3n^2-n^2+n-1}{1-n+n^3-2n^5}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{3}{n^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}-\frac{1}{n^5}}{\frac{1}{n^5}-\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^2}-2}\to 0\end{aligned}$$